# With media queries, is there some 'onViewportChange' function that prompts a search of the .css for relevant styling?

Tags: html, css, browser

So I'm actually not certain on all of the relevant details, but I assume that whenever a new HTML element is created, it iterates through all of the linked-to .css files and inline stylings to see if that styling should be applied to that element.

That implies that there is a callback for style application whenever a function is run to attach a new node to the DOM or whenever a classname is changed. I assume that's how it works.

With media queries, that implies that there is some event listener that is listening for dispatched viewportChange (I'm making up that term, by the way) events and then seeing if any particular dom node needs updating. Is that how it works? It's not practical, because quickly dragging a viewport from 1400px width to 1300px width would fire off 100 events, and cause 100 linear scans through all of the .css and inlined stylings.

Also, I'd love any relevant resources, as I'm trying to learn more and more about modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that media queries are used to override default css styling depending on a certain viewport.

the way it checks this view port is by the browser windows width size. `min-width` or `max-width`

HTML tags are called in css usually by `<tag>`, `#id`, or `.class`.

Not exactly sure what answers you are asking for?

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Well my question is ultimately, *when* it checks. Does it check every time the viewport changes, linearly iterating through all .css files?